# Where to place constants and/or module specific configuration

Tags: module, magento-1, configuration, design-patterns

I have a module that needs smtp authentication information (host, email, method, password, port). I don't want to just hard code this. Where can I put this information where it will have some independence from the code.

For instance, if I wanted to make a JSON that holds this data, where would I place this file in the module structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Magento 1 answer

Magento keeps such information in config.xml files.
You can create a config/default section with your information.

Example:

```
<config>
  ...
  <default>
    <my_module>
      <general>
        <my_setting>my_value</my_setting>
        <my_setting2>my_value2</my_setting2>
      </general>
    </my_module>
  </default>
</config>
```

If you want to allow the admin to change default values you can use a system.xml file for backend config, but please see some tutorial on how to do it because it is too long to explin in a post.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Bonus question, what is the simplest and/or most reliable way to call that from a modules model or controller?

Comment: There is only one way ;) : Mage::getStoreConfig('my_module/general/my_setting');